# Chess programming: minimax, detecting repeats, transposition tables

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, chess, minimax

I'm building a database of chess evaluations (essentially a map from a chess position to an evaluation), and I want to use this to come up with a good move for given positions. The idea is to do a kind of "static" minimax, i.e.: for each position, use the stored evaluation if evaluations for child nodes (positions after next ply) are not available, otherwise use max (white to move)/min (black to move) evaluations of child nodes (which are determined in the same way).

The problem are, of course, loops in the graph, i.e. repeating positions. I can't fathom how to deal with this without making this infinitely less efficient.

The ideas I have explored so far are:

- assume an evaluation of 0 for any position that can be reached in a game with less moves than are currently evaluated. This is an invalid assumption, because - for example - if White plays A, it might not be desirable for Black to follow up with x, but if White plays B, then y -> A -> x -> -B -> -y might be best line, resulting in the same position as A -> x, without any repetitions (-m denoting the inverse move to m here, lower case: Black moves, upper case: White moves).
- having one instance for each possible way a position can be reached solves the loop problem, but this yields a bazillion of instances in some positions and is therefore not practical
- the fact that there is a loop from a position back to that position doesn't mean that it's a draw by repetition, because playing the repeating line may not be best choice
- I've tried iterating through the loops a few times to see if the overall evaluation would become stable. It doesn't, because in some cases, assuming the repeat is the best line means it isn't any longer - and then it goes back to the draw being the back line etc.

I know that chess engines use transposition tables to detect positions already reached before, but I believe this doesn't address my problem, and I actually wonder if there isn't an issue with them: a position may be reachable through two paths in the search tree - one of them going through the same position before, so it's a repeat, and the other path not doing that. Then the evaluation for path 1 would have to be 0, but the one for path 2 wouldn't necessarily be (path 1 may not be the best line), so whichever evaluation the transposition table holds may be wrong, right?

I feel sure this problem must have a "standard / best practice" solution, but google failed me. Any pointers / ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: A complete chessboard configuration can be encoded on 32 bytes. Is that too much ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the size of encoding isn't the problem - I'm fine with this taking terabytes if need be. If you are refering to what I listed as "having one instance for each possible way" - the issue with this is that the algorithm would need to enumerate all those possible ways, and that gets expensive in terms of performance. For example, to reach a position where each side has moved each pawn two fields forward (with no in between moves), there are 8!*8!, roughly 1.6 billion, possible move orders.

Comment: Easiest solution: only store the positions, and treat the history separately (as a stack of hashes)

Comment: Well, after all do you really need to care about loops ? What is the fraction of moves that lead to a loop ? My guess is that this fraction is insignificant. And can they cause poor evaluations ? (Even if the program plays against itself, you can avoid the pat sequences by storing the positions really *played*.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is. A minimax evaluation, unless we've added randomness to it, will have the exact same result for any given board position *combined with who's turn it is and other key info*. If we have the space available to store common `board_position+who's_turn+castling+en passant+draw_related` tuples (or hash thereof), go right ahead. When reaching that tuple in any other evaluation, just return the stored value or rely on its more detailed record for more complex evaluations (if the search yielding that record was not exhaustive, we can have different interpretations for it in any one evaluation). If the program also plays chess with time limits on the game, an additional time dimension (maybe a few broad blocks) would probably be needed in the [memoisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) as well.

(I assume you've read common public info about [transposition tables](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Transposition_Table).)

Comment: I do not think your statement is correct if you take draw by repetition into account, because a node's evaluation depends on how you got there. This means the same position (including whose turn it is) may have a different evaluation if you came there one way than if you had taken another. (And thanks for the links - yes, I did know and have read). Example: the position after 1.Nf3 may have evaluation, say, +0.3. But if I go there by way of 1.Nf3 Nf6 2.Ng1 Ng8 3.Nf3 Nf6 4.Ng1 Ng8 5.Nf3, then that's a threefold repetition, so a draw, and should have evaluation 0.

Comment: @LyingDog that's why it needs to be stored in the hash for the current search state tuple, as I've indicated in the answer (as `draw_related`).

Comment: I see you've added that to your answer now - but what would draw_related actually be? To ultimately solve the problem, it would need to encode the full history since the last non-reversible move, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LyingDog if the aim is to detect threefold repetition anytime in the game it would seem so. But my understanding of the threefold repetition is that in practice it usually occurs within a very small move sequence.

Comment: @LyingDog good question though, how do chess engines typically detect threefold repetition? There seems to be some stuff written about it. The position for the rule is apparently just the board without other info.

Comment: I read through all relevant links mentioning "draw" from the Forum Post section of https://www.chessprogramming.org/Transposition_Table, and the gist of it seems to be: chess engines do something that's actually wrong, but fast, because this gives them higher strength than being right and slow... I wonder if there is a way to exploit this.

Comment: @LyingDog well then you already know more than me about that. For the key in the transposition table, we'd only need the count of how many times the position was repeated so far.